# Synergy stopped moving cursor over to client computer (config worked previously)

Tags: windows, macos, synergy

I am using QuickSynergy on OSX on my client computer and the standard Synergy program on Windows.

I had a configuration that worked two days ago when I last used it, but today I came into work and it wasn't working.

The odd thing is that the server shows that the client connects:

Log:

```
starting server
config file: C:/Users/RTI_US~1/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.gq7972
log level: NOTE
NOTE: started server, waiting for clients
NOTE: accepted client connection
NOTE: client "danbook.local" has connected
```

It's just that the cursor won't move to the other screen. The only change in either of my systems was that I added 4GB of RAM to the client, though that seems unimportant.  What might cause this to happen?

Log with DEBUG2:

```
starting server
config file: C:/Users/RTI_US~1/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.gq6300
log level: DEBUG2
INFO: Synergy 1.4.8 Server on Microsoft Windows 7 x64
DEBUG: opening configuration "C:/Users/RTI_US~1/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.Hp6300"
DEBUG1: thread 0x00000968 entry
DEBUG: opened node pipe: 408
DEBUG: configuration read successfully
DEBUG1: starting server
DEBUG1: thread 0x000014e0 entry
DEBUG: screen shape: 0,0 1680x1050 
DEBUG: window is 0x000a02a4
DEBUG: opened display
DEBUG1: registered event type IScreen::error as 4
DEBUG1: registered event type IScreen::suspend as 5
DEBUG1: registered event type IScreen::resume as 6
DEBUG1: creating primary screen
DEBUG1: binding listen socket
DEBUG1: listening for clients
DEBUG1: registered event type IListenSocket::connecting as 7
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientListener::connected as 8
DEBUG1: registered event type IKeyState::keyDown as 9
DEBUG1: registered event type IKeyState::keyUp as 10
DEBUG1: registered event type IKeyState::keyRepeat as 11
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::buttonDown as 12
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::buttonUp as 13
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::motionPrimary as 14
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::motionSecondary as 15
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::wheel as 16
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::getGameDeviceButtonsEvent as 17
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::getGameDeviceSticksEvent as 18
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::getGameDeviceTriggersEvent as 19
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::getGameDeviceTimingReqEvent as 20
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::screensaverActivated as 21
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::screensaverDeactivated as 22
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer::switchToScreen as 23
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer::switchInDirection as 24
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer:keyboardBroadcast as 25
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer::lockCursorToScreen as 26
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::fakeInputBegin as 27
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::fakeInputEnd as 28
DEBUG1: registered event type IScreen::shapeChanged as 29
DEBUG1: registered event type IScreen::clipboardGrabbed as 30
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientProxy::clipboardChanged as 31
DEBUG: active sides: 0
DEBUG: active sides: 2
DEBUG1: half-duplex caps-lock off
DEBUG1: half-duplex num-lock off
DEBUG1: half-duplex scroll-lock off
DEBUG1: screen saver synchronization on
DEBUG1: Grab the foreground window
DEBUG1: modifiers on update: 0x6000
DEBUG1: thread 0x00001b20 entry
DEBUG: desk Default window is 0x000a030c
DEBUG: switched to desk "Default"
DEBUG: desktop is now accessible
DEBUG1: modifiers on update: 0x6000
DEBUG1: modifiers on update: 0x6000
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::hotKeyDown as 32
DEBUG1: registered event type IPrimaryScreen::hotKeyUp as 33
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer::connected as 34
DEBUG: registered hotkey ScrollLock (id=ef14 mask=0000) as id=1
DEBUG: scroll lock on initially. locked to screen
DEBUG1: registered event type CServer::disconnected as 35
NOTE: started server, waiting for clients
DEBUG1: registered event type reloadConfig as 36
DEBUG1: registered event type forceReconnect as 37
DEBUG1: registered event type resetServer as 38
INFO: screen "RavenglassDan" shape changed
WARNING: log messages above DEBUG1 are NOT sent to console (use file logging)
NOTE: accepted client connection
DEBUG1: registered event type IStream::inputReady as 39
DEBUG1: registered event type IStream::outputError as 40
DEBUG1: registered event type IStream::inputShutdown as 41
DEBUG1: registered event type IStream::outputShutdown as 42
DEBUG1: saying hello
DEBUG2: writef(Synergy%2i%2i)
DEBUG2: wrote 11 bytes
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientProxy::success as 43
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientProxy::failure as 44
DEBUG1: registered event type IStream::outputFlushed as 45
DEBUG1: parsing hello reply
DEBUG2: readf(Synergy%2i%2i%s)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 1 (0x1)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 3 (0x3)
DEBUG2: readf: read 13 byte string: danbook.local
DEBUG1: querying client "danbook.local" info
DEBUG2: writef(QINF)
DEBUG2: wrote 4 bytes
DEBUG1: created proxy for client "danbook.local" version 1.3
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientProxy::ready as 46
DEBUG1: registered event type CClientProxy::disconnected as 47
DEBUG2: msg from "danbook.local": DINF
DEBUG2: readf(%2i%2i%2i%2i%2i%2i%2i)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 0 (0x0)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 0 (0x0)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 1280 (0x500)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 800 (0x320)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 0 (0x0)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 640 (0x280)
DEBUG2: readf: read 2 byte integer: 400 (0x190)
DEBUG: received client "danbook.local" info shape=0,0 1280x800 at 640,400
DEBUG1: send info ack to "danbook.local"
DEBUG2: writef(CIAK)
DEBUG2: wrote 4 bytes
DEBUG: active sides: 0
NOTE: client "danbook.local" has connected
DEBUG1: send reset options to "danbook.local"
DEBUG2: writef(CROP)
DEBUG2: wrote 4 bytes
DEBUG1: send set options to "danbook.local" size=22
DEBUG2: writef(DSOP%4I)
DEBUG2: wrote 96 bytes
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.562381
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.561429
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.560476
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.559524
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.558571
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.557619
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.556667
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.555714
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.556667
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: writef(CALV)
DEBUG2: wrote 4 bytes
DEBUG2: msg from "danbook.local": CALV
DEBUG2: msg from "danbook.local": CNOP
DEBUG2: no-op from
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.555714
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG2: find neighbor on left of "RavenglassDan"
DEBUG2: "danbook.local" is on left of "RavenglassDan" at 0.554762
DEBUG1: try to leave "RavenglassDan" on left
DEBUG: locked to screen
DEBUG1: locked to screen
DEBUG1: event: button press button=1
DEBUG1: onMouseDown id=1
stopping synergy
DEBUG1: event: button release button=1
DEBUG1: onMouseUp id=1
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the service?

Comment: Yes, and the client as well.

Comment: Have you tried redoing your configuration?

Comment: Also, what does the client log say?

Comment: I copied the only stuff it said since starting the server in the post. I don't have access to the server computer right now, but I will post it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Alright, I just want all of the info before I give you advice.

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything exciting. I'm putting the log up top in an edit.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Solved my issue.  **Scroll lock** stops the cursor from going to the other screen.

Comment: Thanks for posting this follow up. (don't mean to resurrect this thread; but it saved me from restarting the computer——like a fool :)

Comment: my god, i've had this problem for about a month now! I have a new Microsoft sculpt desktop keyboard and it doesn't have a led to show scroll lock is even on! Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that even if you remap scroll lock with AutoHotKey, Synergy still does the cursor lock.  Super annoying.

Comment: Ooooh not sure how I knocked scroll lock but that's a good tip to know, useful for gaming and such

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer also works for Barrier. I stumbled upon this answer while troubleshooting the same issue for Barrier. https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/482